# Querying time field using ReactiveMongo and Play JSON

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I am trying to the equivalent of this query using ReactiveMongo with Play Framework & JSON:

```
db.getCollection('people').find({'refreshed': {$gt: ISODate('2017-01-01')}})
```

I tried this:

```
def peopleFuture Future[JSONCollection] database.map(_.collection[JSONCollection]("people"))
```

And run the query:

```
val fromDate = LocalDate.parse("2017-01-01").atStartOfDay()
val query = Json.obj("$gte" -> fromDate)
peopleFuture.flatMap(people => listings.people(query).cursor[JsObject]().collect[List]())
```

This returns an empty sequence.

According to the [documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/json/overview.html), a data/time field is represented as

> JsObject with a $date JsNumber field with the timestamp (milliseconds)
>   as value

However this doesn't seem to help much when querying.

I am using ReactiveMongo 0.12.1 with Play Framework 2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JodaTime` as follow:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime
val fromDate = DateTime.parse("2017-01-01")
val query = Json.obj("refreshed"->Json.obj("$gte" -> Json.obj("$date" -> JsNumber(fromDate.getMillis))))
```